# How to change infoTemplate content depending on the feature layer's fields values

Tags: javascript, field, arcgis

I have the following code:

```
var map;

function init()

{

     map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");

     var basemap: new esri.layer.arcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("link");

     map.addLayer(basemap);



     var content = "Hello!";

     var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();

     infoTemplate.setTitle("<b>${BUILDING_NO}</b>);

     infoTemplate.setTitle(content);



     var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("link",

     mode:esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,

     outFields:["*"],

     infoTemplate:infoTemplate

     });



     map.addLayer(featureLayer);

}
```

---

What I'm trying to do is to change the infoTemplate content depending on the value of one of the fields. any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can setContent with a function for example:

```
        infoTemplate.setContent(getContent);

        function getContent(graphic) {

            var templateContent = '';
            if (graphic.attributes.AssetTypeID === 1) {
                templateContent += 'UpperLimit : ' + graphic.attributes.UpperLimit;
            }
            else if (graphic.attributes.AssetTypeID === 2) {
                templateContent += 'Intersection1  : ' + graphic.attributes.Intersection1;
            }
            return templateContent;
        }
```